# Bind event listener from outside function

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

How can I from the outside of my init function, fire off the reset function within init.

I want my reset function to reset all variables set from the collection of the images (3 in this case) which is bound 3 times. My example here isn't working I'm aware.

Here's my code:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('zoomer-start')[0].addEventListener('click', init);

    document.getElementsByClassName('zoomer-reset')[0].addEventListener('click', reset);

    function init() {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll('.zoomer-img');

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            (function() {
                var image = images[i];

                var zoomer = new Hammer(image);

                zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});

                var clicked = false;

                var adjustScale = 1;
                var adjustDeltaX = 0;
                var adjustDeltaY = 0;

                var currentScale = null;
                var currentDeltaX = null;
                var currentDeltaY = null;

                zoomer.on('tap', function (e) {
                    if (!clicked) {
                        zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: true});
                        zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: true, direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL});
                        clicked = true;
                    } else {
                        zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                        zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});
                        clicked = false;
                    }

                    if (currentScale > 1) {
                        adjustScale = 1;
                        adjustDeltaX = 0;
                        adjustDeltaY = 0;
                    } else {
                        adjustScale = 2;
                    }

                    currentScale = adjustScale * e.scale;
                    currentDeltaX = adjustDeltaX + (e.deltaX / currentScale);
                    currentDeltaY = adjustDeltaY + (e.deltaY / currentScale);

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + currentScale + ') translate3d(' + currentDeltaX + 'px, ' + currentDeltaY + 'px, 0)';
                });

                zoomer.on('pan pinch', function (e) {
                    currentScale = Math.max(1, Math.min(adjustScale * e.scale, 4));
                    currentDeltaX = adjustDeltaX + (e.deltaX / currentScale);
                    currentDeltaY = adjustDeltaY + (e.deltaY / currentScale);

                    var scaledX = ((((image.width * currentScale) / 2) - (image.width / 2)) / currentScale);
                    if (currentDeltaX > scaledX)
                        currentDeltaX = scaledX;
                    if (currentDeltaX < -scaledX)
                        currentDeltaX = -scaledX;

                    var scaledY = ((((image.height * currentScale) / 2) - (image.height / 2)) / currentScale);
                    if (currentDeltaY > scaledY)
                        currentDeltaY = scaledY;
                    if (currentDeltaY < -scaledY)
                        currentDeltaY = -scaledY;

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + currentScale + ') translate3d(' + currentDeltaX + 'px, ' + currentDeltaY + 'px, 0)';
                });

                zoomer.on('panend pinchend', function () {
                    adjustScale = currentScale;
                    adjustDeltaX = currentDeltaX;
                    adjustDeltaY = currentDeltaY;
                });

                function reset() {
                    zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                    zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});

                    clicked = false;

                    adjustScale = 1;
                    adjustDeltaX = 0;
                    adjustDeltaY = 0;

                    currentScale = null;
                    currentDeltaX = null;
                    currentDeltaY = null;

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + 1 + ') translate3d(' + 0 + 'px, ' + 0 + 'px, 0)';
                }
            })();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call function(s) from withinn scope you have to pass it somehow to the surronding scope. One possible example for Your code:

```
var resets = [];
function init() {
[...]
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        (function() {
            [...]
            resets[i]=function reset() {
            [...]
            })
```

And then call them naively:

```
resets[0](); resets[1](); resets[2];
```

Or via:

```
resets.forEach(function(f) { f(); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Having your functions inside the init function gives them Private SCOPE only (can only be accessed from within the init function) To give them global scope you will have to move them outside of the init function which will require some code restructuring.

Comment: I've tried that. Then I cant reset all my variables, only resetting for the last in my images loop.

Comment: Yes thats why you will need to restructure your code. Store your vars in an object that can be accessed globally.

Answer (score 1):

With the code as written, you can't. The `reset` function is entirely private to the code in the anonymous function inside `init`. Even other code in `init` can't access it, much less code *outside* `init`.

I say "it" above, but really, you have multiple `reset` functions, one for each image.

You could, of course, move your code trying to use it as a click handler *into* that anonymous function inside `init`. That's basically your only real option, other than creating an array or similar of `reset` functions that you expose outside `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I learned something today! Here's my working example. Really really neat:

```
    var resets = [];

    document.getElementsByClassName('zoomer-start')[0].addEventListener('click', init);

    document.getElementsByClassName('zoomer-reset')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll('.zoomer-img');

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            resets[i]();
        }
    });

    function init() {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll('.zoomer-img');

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            (function(i) {
                var image = images[i];

                var zoomer = new Hammer(image);

                zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});

                var clicked = false;

                var adjustScale = 1;
                var adjustDeltaX = 0;
                var adjustDeltaY = 0;

                var currentScale = null;
                var currentDeltaX = null;
                var currentDeltaY = null;

                zoomer.on('tap', function (e) {
                    if (!clicked) {
                        zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: true});
                        zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: true, direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL});
                        clicked = true;
                    } else {
                        zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                        zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});
                        clicked = false;
                    }

                    if (currentScale > 1) {
                        adjustScale = 1;
                        adjustDeltaX = 0;
                        adjustDeltaY = 0;
                    } else {
                        adjustScale = 2;
                    }

                    currentScale = adjustScale * e.scale;
                    currentDeltaX = adjustDeltaX + (e.deltaX / currentScale);
                    currentDeltaY = adjustDeltaY + (e.deltaY / currentScale);

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + currentScale + ') translate3d(' + currentDeltaX + 'px, ' + currentDeltaY + 'px, 0)';
                });

                zoomer.on('pan pinch', function (e) {
                    currentScale = Math.max(1, Math.min(adjustScale * e.scale, 4));
                    currentDeltaX = adjustDeltaX + (e.deltaX / currentScale);
                    currentDeltaY = adjustDeltaY + (e.deltaY / currentScale);

                    var scaledX = ((((image.width * currentScale) / 2) - (image.width / 2)) / currentScale);
                    if (currentDeltaX > scaledX)
                        currentDeltaX = scaledX;
                    if (currentDeltaX < -scaledX)
                        currentDeltaX = -scaledX;

                    var scaledY = ((((image.height * currentScale) / 2) - (image.height / 2)) / currentScale);
                    if (currentDeltaY > scaledY)
                        currentDeltaY = scaledY;
                    if (currentDeltaY < -scaledY)
                        currentDeltaY = -scaledY;

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + currentScale + ') translate3d(' + currentDeltaX + 'px, ' + currentDeltaY + 'px, 0)';
                });

                zoomer.on('panend pinchend', function () {
                    adjustScale = currentScale;
                    adjustDeltaX = currentDeltaX;
                    adjustDeltaY = currentDeltaY;
                });

                resets[i] = function reset() {
                    zoomer.get('pinch').set({enable: false});
                    zoomer.get('pan').set({enable: false});

                    clicked = false;

                    adjustScale = 1;
                    adjustDeltaX = 0;
                    adjustDeltaY = 0;

                    currentScale = null;
                    currentDeltaX = null;
                    currentDeltaY = null;

                    image.style.transform = 'scale(' + 1 + ') translate3d(' + 0 + 'px, ' + 0 + 'px, 0)';
                }
            })(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was about to store all my position variables inside a array aswell. That might have worked, and put it global. But this is smaller and smarter, imo.